# What is the use of width:100%!important and height:100%!important in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

```css
.full-block {
  display: block;
}

h1 {
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.block-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
}

.block-2 {
  width: 100%!important;
  height: 100%!important;
  background-color: #6a9e77;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-block">
  <div class="block-1">
    <h1>BLOCK 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="block-2">
    <h1>BLOCK 2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the height and width of this two blocks is the same even if `!important` is used. So actually what is the use of `width:100%!important` and `height:100%!important` in CSS?

Comment: In this case, there’s no need to use `!important`, and in general you should never use `!important`. Selector specificity is enough.

Comment: so `!important` should not be used? right? but i see a lot of people use this a lot... don't know why? :( @Ryan

Comment: Its a very bad practice: it  forbids other styles not important to override this style.
Just as bad as using inline styles.

Comment: oh i see, so this must be deprecated @ChristianPastorCruz

Comment: Does `!important` effects page load time as inline CSS usually do? @ChristianPastorCruz

Comment: No, @SifaturRahman, neither !important nor inline styles are close from being deprecated.

Comment: Think about old style attributes. As many useful websites still uses them they are still around. Just like this:
<a href="#" color="red">text</a>

Comment: @ChristianPastorCruz Okey-dokey.. got some really helpful advice from you bro.. thanks

Comment: @ChristianPastorCruz and any others. Ignore anyone who tells you never to use !important or that it is on the way out. It's a mark of one who doesn't understand CSS or how to use it. It's a perfectly valid property that will be around forever and in no way is considered bad practice by professionals who know what they're doing.

Answer (score 4):

The use of "!important" is used when you have multiple specifications of "width" or "height" in your CSS and want to override which one is used. Otherwise, the default is that the latest specification is used. The preference is to not need "!important", but it is there for those special situations. Also note that some older browsers do not support it (such as IE6).

For example:

```
.obj
{
 width:600px;
 width:800px; /* This one is used*/
}
```

But using !important...

```
.obj
{
 width:600px !important; /* This one is used */
 width:800px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`!important` is used to override other CSS rules for the same parameter of the same element/s which have the same or lower specifity (google specifity, it could be compared to "complexity of the CSS selector"), for example in Wordpress to override settings that are already defined in the theme CSS which you can't or wouldn't want to change. Sometimes people just use it to override other settings when they don't know what else to do, which is bad practice...

However, in your particular example, it has no use at all - already the `100%` before it doesn't have any use at all, since 100% width is the default setting for block elements anyway, and 100% height needs a defined `height` setting of the parent element to relate to, which doesn't exist in this case.

Comment: hmm... as a block element covers 100% width and 100% height... i agree i shouldn't have used that.. but i need to know the difference.

Comment: `auto` is the default width of block elements, not 100%. They're only the same if there's no margins, borders or padding (for box-sizing:content-box) or just no margins (for box-sizing:border-box).

Comment: it doesn't cover 100% *height*  by default. By default the height is determined by its contents - like in the example in the question, where the 100% height doesn't have any effect since the parent elements don't have a defined height.

Comment: yes, understood bro. the child element utilizes the space of parent element not more than that as long as child element is not set to absolute position.. am i right.. broz?